# Array en typescript

Tags: javascript, array, typescript

tengo un array de este tipo;

```
[

{
Ciudad: 'madrid',
Nombre: 'luis'
Edad: 25
}

{
Ciudad: 'madrid',
Nombre: 'mirna'
Edad: 29
}

{
Ciudad: 'sevilla',
Nombre: 'alejandro'
Edad: 18
}

]
```

Y me gustaría que quedará asi:

```
[


{

Ciudad: 'madrid',
{
Nombre: 'luis',
Edad: 25
},
{
Nombre: 'mirna',
Edad:29
}
}

{

Ciudad:'sevilla',
{

Nombre: 'alejandro',
Edad: 18


}

}


]
```

Alguien sabe que funcion me serviría?

Comment: Asi se entiende menos beta, yo probe lo mismo :(

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! a ver si podes arreglar tu pregunta.. tenes un array de objetos y vos qures que esos objetos sean de otra forma? es muy dudoso que encuentres una funcion que haga eso.. tal vez deberias transformarlos a mano? intentaste algo?

Comment: Yo usaría `reduce`, comprobando si en el acumulador ya está la ciudad para añadir otro sujeto o hay que añadirla antes

Comment: Pablo, como lo tendria que hacer con reduce?